# Generalized Forces in the Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I have resolved this problem:
[image]
The lagrangian is only the kinetic part in the non-inertial frame:
$$ L(x, \theta) = \dfrac{1}{2}m \dot{\textbf{r}}^2 $$
where $\textbf{r}'= \tilde{\textbf{R}}+\textbf{r}$, $\textbf{r}$ the position vector of $m$ in the non-inertial frame from $O$, $\textbf{r}'$ the position vector of $m$ in the inertial frame from $F$, $\tilde{\textbf{R}}$ the position vector of the non-inertial frame $O$ from $F$. Note that
$$ \theta = \omega t $$ is the position of $O$ from $F$, and $x(0)=a$. So from the texts
$$ \textbf{a}_F = \textbf{a}_O +\textbf{A} + 2\vec{\omega}\times \textbf{v}_O +\vec{\omega}\times (\vec{\omega} \times \textbf{r}) + \dot{\vec{\omega}} \times \textbf{r}  = \begin{pmatrix} \ddot{x} \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} + 0 + \begin{pmatrix} -\omega^2 x \\ 2 \omega \dot{x} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} +\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\-h\omega^2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + 0.$$
Hence,
$$ m(\ddot{x}-\omega^2 x) =0 \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad x(t) = a \cosh \omega t$$
and
$$\textbf{F}\equiv  \textbf{R}_O= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 2m \omega \dot{x}-hm\omega^2\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}_O = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ m\omega^2 (2\sqrt{x^2-a^2} -h) \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}_O$$
from $O$.

> Generalized force $Q$ is $ \omega^2 x$? What are the Lagrange-Euler equations?

The second part is
[image]
[image]

> How I add the new strings in the lagrangian? Where does the critical frequency come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings' contribution is added to the potential energy.
$$L(x,t)_{new} = L(x,t)_{old} - \frac{1}{2}k x^2 \cdot 2$$
Factor $2$ comes from the fact that one spring is streched by length $x$ and another is squeezed by the same length.